# MVC 4 EF5 Primary Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, primary-key

In my application my user model has a foreign key to the address table. My problem is after I insert the the address into the address table I have to run a LINQ query on the whole population of the address table looking for the record I just persisted. Is there a better way to get the primary key from a record that was just persisted?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change the primary key type to GUID, which is UNIQUEIDENTIFIER in SQL. then you will know your inserted id:

```
var id = Guid.NewGuid();
var model = new Address()
{
    Id = id,
    // ...
};
// add and save context
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon `SaveChanges()`, the Context will update your Entity with the newly-created id.